# JSON file for google vision text detection

Tags: json

I want to detect chinese characters. So I follow google API to include the "languageHints" key. However, the request has problems and errors are returned. I am not sure whether I set the latLongRect and cropHintsParams correctly. Can anyone please help? Thank you very much.

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "features": [
       {
         "type": "TEXT_DETECTION",
         "maxResults": 10
       },
       {
         "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION",
         "maxResults": 10
       }
     ],
      "image": { "content": "xxx"},

      "imageContext": {

        "latLongRect": {
           "minLatLng": {
             "latitude": "-180",
             "longitude": "-90"
           },
           "maxLatLng": {
             "latitude": "180",
             "longitude": "90"
           }
        },

        "languageHints": [
           "zh*"
        ],

        "cropHintsParams": {
          "aspectRatios": [
            "10"
          ]
        }
      }

   }
  ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

json data shown above has syntax error and it is not well formed.

You can use any online json parser (for e.g. http://jsonparseronline.com/) to check if json is well-formed.

it will help if you can give details of error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I corrected the code but I still got the error from google: {'responses': [{'error': {'code': 14, 'message': 'Service temporarily unavailable. Error processing features.'}}]}

Comment: Thank you for your website. I missed a comma, now the code is ok. I used google vision api. The code is 'response = requests.post(url='https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=abc, data=data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})'

Comment: So now is it working and the above error only due to - Service temporarily unavailable? If so then this error handling explanation as per (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Code) is to retry after sometime.

Comment: Thank you very much, v.j